# How to fix cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't find where the culprit is. I tried to debug it, but can't found what really make it those error:

> cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')   &&
> react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (  
    <React.Fragment> 
      <Counter/>
    </React.Fragment> 
  );
}
        
export default App;
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider context={StoreContext} store={Store()}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
          
reportWebVitals();
```

CounterReducer.js

```
const CounterReducer = (state = { count: 0 } , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case handleDencrement:
      return state.count - 1 
            
    case handleIncrement:
      return state.count + 1
    
    default:
      return state
  } 
}
     
export default CounterReducer;
```

context.js

```
const StoreContext = React.createContext();
     
export default StoreContext ;
```

Store.js

```
const Store = () => {
  const store = useStore(CounterReducer); 
      
  return store
}
export default Store;
```

types.js

```
export const handleIncrement = 'handleIncrement' ;
    
export const handleDencrement = 'handleDencrement';
```

Counter.js

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
    
  const handleIncrement = () => {  
    setcount(count + 1);
  }
    
  const handleDencrement = () => {  
    setcount(count - 1);
  }
     
  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h1>Redux</h1>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={handleDencrement}>decrement</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Counter;
```

Comment: The `context` prop of the redux `Provider` component is for very advanced use cases only.  You do not need this.  In fact I can't even explain what it's for because in all my years of react-redux I have never used it.

Answer (score 6):

My issue was solved with Next.js by just stopping the server using 'Ctrl + C'. And restarted the server using 'npm run dev'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: lol this was it for me

Comment: what if this problem happens on production? am i supposed to shut down the whole system and restart it again all the time every time it happens and disrupt UX?

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

`Store` isn't a React component so it can't use the `useStore` hook.

[`useStore`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usestore)

> This hook returns a reference to the same Redux store that was passed
> in to the `<Provider>` component.

In other words, the `useStore` hook is expecting a Redux Context to be provided to it from higher in the ReactTree.

## Solution

From what I can tell of the code it seems you want the `Store` function to create and return a Redux store object, to be passed to the `Provider` component.

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import counter from '../path/to/counter.reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

types

```
export const handleIncrement = 'handleIncrement' ;
export const handleDecrement = 'handleDecrement';
```

counter.reducer.js

The reducer function should maintain the state invariant. In this case the state is an object with a `count` property.

```
const counterReducer = (state = { count: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case handleDecrement:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1
      }; 

    case handleIncrement:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

index.js

```
...
import store from '../path/to/store';
...

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Counter

Instead of using local component state the component should use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks to read and update the `counter` state in the store.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Counter = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const count = useSelector(state => state.counter.count);

  const handleIncrement = () => {  
    dispatch({ type: handleIncrement });
  }

  const handleDecrement = () => {  
    dispatch({ type: handleDecrement });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h1>Redux</h1>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={handleDecrement}>decrement</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone, therefore adding to the answers.
I had the same problem and it was the result of a silly mistake. While installing react bootstrap, I did npm install in the parent folder instead of project folder itself. When I later did npm install in the project folder itself the error was gone.

It was silly, for real.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the answer was that I accidentally installed the locked package again, deleted it and it ran

Comment: And with what did you lock it? A bike lock? Wait, ..., no that can't be true. Did you, by any chance, mean `package-lock.json`? In that case add a summary why this works. For the meantime, I recommend deletion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642874)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall node-packages. or

**include change directory command before installing any package if you are using new terminal everytime.**

**so it creates only one node-modules,package-lock.json and package.json for the entire project.**

like this:

```
npx create-react-app projectname
cd addtocart
npm start

cd projectname
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap –save

cd projectname
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit

cd projectname
npm install react-redux
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I was using framer motion library the first time.

If you install any kind of library like `npm install framer-motion`,
you should stay in your project directory, then the library should show up in on your
`package.json` file.

That's the way you can get rid of the "`can not read properties of null`".

Answer (score 0):

I install one package outside of root folder. Then I removed the extra json file. Then I go to root folder by cd client command and install my package.then restart my project.
worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that one of my dependencies was using a different version (greater) of `react` and `react-dom`.

To force my dependencies to use the same version as my main `package.json` file, i've used the `resolutions` feature from **yarn**: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

If you're using **npm**, take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35505009)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem and solved it by changing the version of react-bootstrap in package.json file.

delete all your node_modules, change the version like this:

"react-bootstrap": "2.9.2",

and after that, install your project again.

Answer (score -1):

Delete and Reinstall the npm modules ,
Using the command = npm install, you can install npm modules.

This will resolve the error.